# Can we add shape in turtle.shape()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, whiteboard

I want to code whiteboard program so I want to change shape of turtle to pen.
I wanna know Do we have something in turtle to add further - like pen - shape in `turtle.shape()`?
and if we have it, how can we add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to adding a new turtle cursor shape is the screen method `register_shape()` (aka `addshape()`).  You can define the new shape either using polygons (individual or multiple) or an image file (traditionally a *.GIF but more recently also *.PNG, depending on the underlying version of tkinter).

Once a shape is registered, it can be used with the turtle `shape()` method to change the cursor to the new shape.  Based on the turtle documentation:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.register_shape("custom.gif")

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape("custom.gif")
```

However, images don't rotate with the turtle.  For that, you can define a polygon-based shape:

```
screen.register_shape("right_triangle", ((-10, 10), (-10, -10), (10, -10)))

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape("right_triangle")
```

Though the polygon image might not be oriented the way you expect so you may need to rotate your turtle or adjust your polygon coordinates.